# Type error with Either in TypeScript/fp-ts

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I'm using fp-ts and I have a function that returns either an HttpError object or a string:

```
async getPreferencesForUserId(userId: string): Promise<Either<HttpResponseNotFound, string>> {
    const preferences = await getRepository(Preference).findOne({ userId });
    return preferences ? right(preferences.preferenceMap) : left(new HttpResponseNotFound({ code: 404, message: 'Could not find preferences' }));
  }
```

I would like to call this function in another file like this:

```
const preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError: Either<HttpResponseNotFound, string> = await this.preferenceService.getPreferencesForUserId(userId);

const response: HttpResponseOK | HttpResponseNotFound = pipe(preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError, fold(
  e => e,
  r => new HttpResponseOK(r)
));
response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

return response;
```

This is basically how I'd do it in Scala. (with the exception that `fold` is a method on the Either type, not a standalone function - so here I'm using the `pipe` helper)

The problem is, I'm getting an error from ts-server:

```
Type 'HttpResponseOK' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponseNotFound': isHttpResponseNotFound, isHttpResponseClientError
```

And

```
node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Either.d.ts:129:69                                                                           
    129 export declare function fold<E, A, B>(onLeft: (e: E) => B, onRight: (a: A) => B): (ma: Either<E, A>) => B;
                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

I can get around this issue by doing this in a much more imperative way:

```
const preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError: Either<HttpResponseNotFound, string> = await this.preferenceService.getPreferencesForUserId(userId);
if (isLeft(preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError)) {
  return preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError.left;
}

const response = new HttpResponseOK(preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError.right);
response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

return response;
```

But I pretty much lose the benefit of using an Either at that point.

Comment: The way TS works (and the fold signature is written) you won't get unification there, see a very similar discussion here: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/pull/945

Comment: So is `fold` not the right thing to use if I just want either the value or an error?

Comment: drafted an answer below, let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes, the more I sat back and thought about it yesterday, the more I realized OF COURSE `fold` expects homogeneous types. I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that, given how TS inference works, when using `fold`, its return type is "fixed" to the one of the first argument (`onLeft`), and `onRight` is not able to "widen" it `HttpResponseNotFound | HttpResponseOK`.

In other words, you will not get unification for free in the general case using TS and fp-ts.

For this specific scenario, I would suggest to

1. give a name to the union type you want in output (not strictly necessary, but helps in clarifying intent):

```
type HttpResponse = HttpResponseNotFound | HttpResponseOK
```

2. explicitly "widen" the return type of fold. This has to be done manually, either by annotating the return type of the `onLeft` `fold` argument:

```
const response: HttpResponse = pipe(
  preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError,
  E.fold((e): HttpResponse => e, r => new HttpResponseOK(r))
)
```

or by defining a `widen` helper as follows:

```
const widen = E.mapLeft<HttpResponse, HttpResponse>(e => e);

const response: HttpResponse = pipe(
  preferenceMapAsJsonStringOrError,
  widen,
  E.fold(identity, r => new HttpResponseOK(r))
);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This looks great! Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

I still get type errors after when trying the 2 methods. What fixed it for me was explicitly specifying the type of the fold.

```
fold<HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponseOK, HttpResponseNotFound | HttpResponseOK>(
  e => e,
  r => new HttpResponseOK(r)
)
```